# How to terminate a running DolphinDB query

Tags: dolphindb

Sometimes after I execute a query in DolphinDB database, I realize that the query scans the entire database and would take an extremely long time to finish. Is there a way I can terminate a running query in DolphinDB without closing the session? I can't find the answer in the user manual.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you submit the query through GUI or web. Simply open another GUI or web to run function `getConsoleJobs` to identify the job id (in format of UUID) and then call `cancelConsoleJob`